# Pre Chat Form with a Custom Chat Page

Tags: liveagent, chat, pre-chat

I am having an issue with my pre-chat form and my custom chat page in my live chat deployment.

If I remove the pre chat page from this configuration I can go to my custom chat page but if I have both defined then after I enter my details into the pre chat page I just get redirected to a new pre chat page without any of the stuff I just filled in.

Has anyone seen this? Is there a work around?

Thanks!

[image: Chat BUtton Definition]

Comment: Can you include both your pre-chat form and chat page vf component?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using preChat and customChat page configuration, do not open preChat page from visualforce and try submitting.

When you do this, it does not contain any reference to the chat button settings configured.

Instead only use the page that has the button code and deployment code to test the livechat functionality.

Let me know if it helps, or if you are facing any issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question, but rather a request for clarification. You'd do that by adding a comment to the question, but you need at least 50 reputation score to do that (you should contribute to questions that do not need clarification for now). Though given the question is almost 4 years old, I doubt you'd get a response.